# How to build a hierarchical section/subsection/paragraph "path"

Tags: xml, xslt

I know this is different from the original question but it was a thought process i was thinking of to achieve the below desired result:

XML INPUT :

```
<section hangIndent="no" indent="arabic 1 digit"
isProposedAmendment="no" label="2A">
<title>AAA</title>
<body>
 BBB<subSection label="1">
  <body>
    <para hangIndent="yes" indent="loweralpha 1 character"
     isProposedAmendment="no" label="a">
      <body>
        CCC
      </body>
    </para>
    <para hangIndent="yes" indent="loweralpha 1 character"
      isProposedAmendment="no" label="b">
      <body>
        DDD
      </body>
    </para>
    <para hangIndent="yes" indent="loweralpha 1 character"
     isProposedAmendment="no" label="c">
      <body>
        EEE
      </body>
    </para>
  </body>
</subSection>
</body>
<annotation isProposedAmendment="no">
FFFFF
</annotation>
</section>
```

desired output : i build a xmlpath name based on the label of each node and insert it at each end point.

```
<nm:xmlpath name ="2A" />
<section hangIndent="no" indent="arabic 1 digit"
isProposedAmendment="no" label="2A">
<title>AAA</title>
<body>
 BBB
<nm:xmlpath name ="2A 1" /> 
<subSection label="1">
  <body>
    <nm:xmlpath name ="2A 1(a)" />
    <para hangIndent="yes" indent="loweralpha 1 character"
isProposedAmendment="no" label="a">
      <body>
        CCC
      </body>
    </para>
    <nm:xmlpath name ="2A 1(b)" />
    <para hangIndent="yes" indent="loweralpha 1 character"
  isProposedAmendment="no" label="b">
      <body>
        DDD
      </body>
    </para>
    <nm:xmlpath name ="2A 1(c)" />
    <para hangIndent="yes" indent="loweralpha 1 character"
  isProposedAmendment="no" label="c">
      <body>
        EEE
      </body>
    </para>
  </body>
</subSection>
</body>
<annotation isProposedAmendment="no">
FFFFF
</annotation>
</section>
```

Comment: But at this rate, **without a root element** your XML might become invalid one! Are you okay with that?

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' its test data of a huger xml which will have a root. thanks.

Comment: If there is more context then please show us a sample of both the transformation's input and the wanted output including a root element, otherwise it is hard to suggest code.

Comment: @luckyluke, nope, no matter how big your input XML is .. provided your requirement and solution by Martin, output XML won't have root.. for sure..

Comment: This code sample of yours gives entirely different requirement than what you posted earlier.. What I see is .. you are adding an extra element `<nm:xmlpath name ="2A 1(a)" />` before a set of nodes, where the name depends on label of following node..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic approach would be to have a template that matches any element that has a `label` attribute, and before that element insert an `nm:xmlpath` constructed from all the `label` attributes you find on parents, grandparents, etc.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:nm="urn:nm-namespace">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@label]">
    <nm:xmlpath>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="xmlpath" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </nm:xmlpath>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- templates to construct the xmlpath, these should produce text nodes -->

  <!-- general case - path is the enclosing path (if any), followed by space,
       followed by our own @label -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="xmlpath">
    <xsl:if test="ancestor::*[@label]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@label][1]" mode="xmlpath" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@label" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special case for para - no space after enclosing path, and surround
       our label with () -->
  <xsl:template match="para" mode="xmlpath">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@label][1]" mode="xmlpath" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', @label, ')')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In order for this to produce well-formed XML the root element of your input document must *not* have a `label` attribute - if it did we'd be trying to insert an `nm:xmlpath` before it, giving the output document two root-level elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should suffice.

Comment: The OP has changed the question, inturn has changed the requirement!! I pretty much liked your answer which was short and perfect enough for earlier requirement!!